# A user-centric multi-site installation

Tags: nodes, multi-sites

How do I go about creating a similar content-structure as wordpress.com?

- I want the user experience to only be of the sub-site (sub-site.example.com) and not of the main website (example.com). E.g. the home link goes to the sub-site, like this http://fiveandspice.wordpress.com/
- In my case I will not offer blogs, but a web-application.
- I'm thinking of utilizing Drupal for the user-system to handle the subscription-based accounts and generating the web pages.
- The account-owners will have visits to their "page", and those visitors in turn would as well need account to do certain actions. Similar to how Basecamp work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the Aegir hosting System http://www.aegirproject.org/
It presents an intuitive front end to multisite.

Comment: The Aegir project seems like the best solution, but it's a pity that this process still is so much more cumbersome than on Wordpress. The serious lack of good documentation and active support discussion makes it as well hard to grasp what potential issues might arise.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Subdomain](https://www.drupal.org/project/subdomain) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Automatically creates subdomains and places content on them. There are 4 modes:
>
> - **User**: e.g. "Mary" and content at http://mary.example.com
> - **Taxonomy**: e.g. "Seattle" and content at http://seattle.example.com
> - **Organic Group**: e.g. "MyGroup" and content at http://mygroup.example.com
> - **Content type subdomains**: e.g. "News" content at http://news.example.com